# addmethod in jquery.validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How to use addmethod in jquery.validate.
Example

```
$("#formname").validate({
    rules: {
        textbox: {
            required: true,
            regexp: /['"]/
        },
        methods: {
            required: "Should not be blank",
            regexp: "Single quotes and double quotes not allowed"
        }
    }
});
```

I need to check this quotes in textbox with addmethod. How can i do this. Explain me by implementing your answer with my sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need a few fixes, the layout for `messages` is like this (you can't do this with your original options...the plugin just doesn't look for that structure):

```
$("#formname").validate({
    rules: {
        textbox: {
            required: true,
            regexp: /['"]/
        }
    },
    messages: {
        textbox: {
            required: "Should not be blank",
            regexp: "Single quotes and double quotes not allowed"
        }
    }
});
```

Then your method would look like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("regexp", function(value, element, param) { 
  return this.optional(element) || !param.test(value); 
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/FB8Dz/)....but you notice your regex is backwards, so the naming's not quite right...I'd rename `regexp` to `nomatch`...or something more indicative of the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#formname").validate({
  rules: {
    textbox: {
        required: true,
        regexp: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
     textbox: {
         required: "Should not be blank",
         regexp: "Single quotes and double quotes not allowed"
     }
  }
});



// Regexp validation
$.validator.addMethod("regexp", function(value, element, arg){
var reg_val=$('#textbox').val();
var regExp=/^['"]+$/;

if($('#textbox').val().match(reg_val)){
  return true;
}else{
   return false;
}
}, "");
```